# Jmeter and global Beanshell variables

Tags: java, json, variables, jmeter, amazon-kinesis

Is it possible in jmeter to use the same variables in different BeanShell Sampler?
My target is import my Amazon Kinesis Java application (converted  ) into Jmeter, but part of this code is the connection and I want to set-up this once at the start-up of jmeter application. So I must re-use AmazonKinesisClient variable in different beanshell. Is it possible?
thanks

PS: I have the same problem with JSONObject but in such case I have used a jmeter variable (storing json as String)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `bsh.shared` namespace as per [Sharing Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_variables) chapter of JMeter Best Practices guide.

In the first sampler:

```
JSONObject myObject = new JSONObject();
....
bsh.shared.myObject = myObject;
```

In the second (or whatever) sampler:

```
JSONObject myObject = bsh.shared.myObject;
```

For more Beanshell tips and tricks refer to [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide.

Answer (score 0):

If Both beanshell samplers are in the same thread, beanshell vars are shared between them.

```
vars.putObject("name",objectRef);
vars.getObject(“name”);
```